# Android stack imageView on top of other components

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have some problem when trying to layout my Android Activity. So basically I have a layout with one edit text field and a button next to it. I wanted an imageview on top of both of them for a few seconds and disappear after that. Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchAddrET"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:hint="Enter search address, eg. postal code"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivZoomGuide"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/event_zoom_guide"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSearchAddr"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSearchAddr"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@color/lightred"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

And from my Java code, I am trying to bring the imageview to front by this:

```
ivZoomGuide.bringToFront();
```

However, I am getting this output:

[image]

The imageview which is the blur color thing does not float on top of both of them. Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think frame layout might help you

Comment: Your parent layout is LinearLayout and in that layout you cannot draw on top of another object. Also you have an attribute: android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSearchAddr" in your ImageView and it's only supported if you use RelativeLayout as parent. I suggest that you change your Parent layout to Relative layout, add the EditText and Button first and then put the ImageView on top of them. Then in the code you call setVisibility(View.GONE) for the ImageView after the delay you had in mind.

Comment: @wldchld Hold on. Let me modify the codes

Comment: If will be better to use android:animateLayoutChanges="true" while switching the layout. This make your frame animated. :)

Comment: @wldchld If I changed to relative layout, the relative layout just took the whole page instead of showing at the bottom of the screen. Do you have any ideas? I checked the layout_height attribute and it was set to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should look like this

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchAddrET"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:hint="Enter search address, eg. postal code"
                android:textSize="12dp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSearchAddr"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@color/lightred"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivZoomGuide"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/event_zoom_guide"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSearchAddr"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: With the frame layout, do I still need the code which bring the imageview to front?

Comment: You still need to handle showing and hiding imageview.